# ng-repeat and filter issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that consists of an activity item.  Activity items consist of a title, description, and type (all strings).  I have three input filters (title and description are done via textbox, type is done via select) that are set up with ng-model written as activityFilter.Title, activityFilter.Description, activityFilter.Type.

I have two questions from this:
1) I'm not sure why, but if I type a filter in the Description box, nothing happens (the filter does not occur).  When I clear the Description box, the number of activity items doubles and then goes back to the proper number shortly thereafter.  I'm assuming that there is a digest cycle period that resets it back to the correct number of items, but any thoughts as to why it would be doubling up when I clear it?

2) There is potential for there to be as many as 1000 activity items in this list.  I'm already noticing performance issues when I get to 100 or so items.  Is there a better way to do do things then use ng-repeat that will still take advantage of filters?

3) Currently I have the ng-repeat section done with a series of divs.  Would it help improve performance if I switched it to an ng-repeat of directives?

I'm using Angular 1.3.x.

Comment: For the second question, have you tried lazy loading? Set a filter to limit the amount of entries loaded initially, and increase that number once the user starts scrolling down slowly.

Comment: @AlvinJ - That's not an option for me right now because the system has to work offline as well.  The system, as it's built right now, loads everything for a particular project when the user initially connects to the server, then on an interval basis merges new data and sends any changes. I need to have it this way to allow the user to disconnect at any time and continue working.

Comment: For question 1, can you provide some code? For question 2, try bind-once https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce . For 3, using repeated directives would probably slow it down more, even more so on mobile device.

Comment: Thanks @SoluableNonagon.  I tried to recreate the issue in plunkr but I couldn't.  I rewrote that portion of my page and #1 seems to be resolved.  If I can recreate it, I'll re-post.  For #2, I used the Angular JS 1.3 version of bind once and that worked great..thanks for the suggestion!  For #3, I decided to stick with the html markup and added a track by clause to my ng-repeat and that seems to have made things run a good amount faster.

Comment: @AlvinJ - Thanks for your suggestion on the limitTo.  I actually added this to my ng-repeat and it has helped things tremendously.  I load the entire data set into the model but use the limitTo method to limit what is displayed to screen, that seems to have alleviated a LOT of my performance issues